# How to change WiFi settings of HP Laserjet P1102W?

Tags: wireless-networking, hp-laserjet

Does anybody know how to change the WiFI settings (SSID and password of the host network) for HP Laserjet P1102W? This printer comes with an integrated Wifi adaptor and detects the initial wifi settings automatically during installation. Last week I changed my Wifi router and couldn't find a way to reconfigure my printer for it.

Answer (score 7):

In the install directory for the 1100 series there is an executable that takes you through the reconfiguration of the P1102w wireless settings. 
In Win 7 in 
(C:\Program Files\HP\HP LaserJet P1100 Series)
The executable is 
(wificonfig.exe)
Run this with the printer next to your laptop or desktop with the printer on and a USB cable available but not connected, and follow the instructions given by the program. This takes you through the wifi setup without the tedium of uninstalling and reinstalling anything.

Comment: The Linux hplip equivalent is `hp-wificonfig`.

Comment: the wificonfig.exe included with the P1102w is blocked by windows 10 due to a bad signature... hp hasn't updated the driver since WTF!?!

Comment: At one point wificonfig.exe was waiting for the printer to try to connect to the WiFi network. I had to press the WiFi button on the printer to get this happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your router's config, change it to match your previous router, log into the http interface of the printer and change settings to new values from there.  The printer will save them and become unavailable until you restore the settings you saved as per beginning of this message.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed the software/printer and set a wifi password, the installation disk (as described in the video) won't prompt you to setup wifi.

Instead, you must uninstall the HP software, and then run the setup again using the install disk.  This time, it will prompt for your wifi credentials.